# How to add data to the properties created locally under test case in Soapui Pro?

Tags: groovy, properties, automation, soapui, testcase

I have TestCase under a TestSuite step in the project. Inside test case, there are **Properties** test step and **Groovy script** test step.

Properties step, I added a property like **Pro_Response** and default value as **Nothing**

Similarly, I used the following groovy script for assigning a string value to the property and then it shows the string in the log.

```
String testString = "TestString"
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue( "Pro_Response", testString )
def getLocalPropValue = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("Pro_Response")
log.info(getLocalPropValue)
```

**Question:** Why the string value is not updating in the property step which I added under the test case even the same property name (i.e. **Pro_Response**) is used in the script  for assigning?

**Please refer the screenshot for your reference:**
[image]

Thanks,
Karunagara Pandi

Answer (score 1):

You have added a "Properties" Test **Step**, but your script is updating a property in the Test **Case**. Update your script to:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Properties"].setPropertyValue( "Pro_Response", testString )
```

Comment: If the answer is satisfactory, you can click to accept it and upvote it.